# Problem with Imagemagick after upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04

Tags: imagemagick, ubuntu-20.04

Recently I upgraded Ubuntu to the 20.04 version.
Unfortunately,  after the upgrade, the problems with Imagemagick appeared.

```
$ magick
magick: error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf-2_2.so.22: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same errors with libIlmImf is returned when use **identify** or **convert** command.
As an inexperienced user of Ubuntu, I think I could mess something up with packages trying to solve it.

```
apt list --installed | grep magick

graphicsmagick/focal,now 1.4+really1.3.35-1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
imagemagick-6-common/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 all [installed,automatic]
imagemagick-6.q16/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed]
libgraphicsmagick-q16-3/focal,now 1.4+really1.3.35-1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-6/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6.q16-6/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

which magick
/usr/local/bin/magick
```

Grepping **libIlmImf** also returns different versions that are expected:

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libIlmImf

libIlmImf-2_3.so.24
libIlmImf-2_3.so.24.0.0
libIlmImf.a
libIlmImf.so
libIlmImfUtil-2_3.so.24
libIlmImfUtil-2_3.so.24.0.0
libIlmImfUtil.a
libIlmImfUtil.so
```

Does anyone encounter issues with Imagemagick after the upgrade? Do you have some suggestions that may help me?

Comment: Looks like your `libIlmImf` is one minor version newer than the one **ImageMagick** wants. I would make a backup first, then try uninstalling and reinstalling **ImageMagick**. If that doesn't help, you could try using the package manager to install v2.2 of Ilm and then reinstalling **ImageMagick**, or you could see if you get lucky by making a symlink in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` with `ln -s libIlmImf-2_3.so.24 libIlmImf-2_2.so.22` Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark Setchell wrote

> Looks like your libIlmImf is one minor version newer than the one ImageMagick wants

Unfortunately, I could not install packages in lower versions because of dependencies and I did not try making a symlink.

But I get it running by downloading older packages from **ubuntuupdates**

[libopenexr22](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/security/libopenexr22)
[libilmbase](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/base/libilmbase12)

Then I copied these files to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and now all commands: `identify`, `convert` and `magick` works good.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you @mark-setchell! Symlink works in my case!

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ln -s libIlmImf-2_3.so.24 libIlmImf-2_2.so.22
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem came up when I updated the Heroku stack from Ubuntu 18 to 20.
Given that I cannot download new packages or create symlinks, what fixed it for me was using the [HiMamaInc buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/himamainc/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick-heif)